# Qt Beginner: QPainter widget not rendering

Tags: c++, qt, qpainter

I don't have much experience with Qt and I am having trouble using `QPainter`.
I am trying to make a simple graphing widget which takes in a number of points and to create a `QVector` of `QPoints`, and then uses this vector to draw a polygon. However, nothing is appearing right now with my implementation. I am fairly certain that I have added the widget correctly to the window, as I can see the empty space it should occupy. This leads me to believe the problem to be in the graphing widget.
Any assistance is appreciated.

header:

```
//graph.h

#ifndef GRAPH_H
#define GRAPH_H

#include <QWidget>
#include <QPainter>
#include <QVector>

class Graph : public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    Graph(QWidget *parent = 0);
    QSize minimumSizeHint() const;
    QSize maximumSizeHint() const;
    QSize sizeHint() const;

    void addPoint(int w, int h);
    void clearPoints();
    void drawGraph();


protected:
    void paintEvent(QPaintEvent *event);


private:
    QPen pen;
    QBrush brush;
    QPixmap pixmap;
    QVector<QPoint> points;

};

#endif // GRAPH_H
```

source:

```
//graph.cpp

#include "graph.h"

Graph::Graph(QWidget *parent)
    : QWidget(parent)
{
    points.resize(0);

    setBackgroundRole(QPalette::Base);
    setAutoFillBackground(true);
}

void Graph::paintEvent(QPaintEvent *event)
{
    QPainter painter(this);
    painter.setPen(QPen(Qt::NoPen));
    painter.setBrush(QBrush(Qt::green, Qt::SolidPattern));
    painter.setRenderHint(QPainter::Antialiasing, true);
    painter.drawPolygon(points);
}

QSize Graph::minimumSizeHint() const
{
    return sizeHint();
}

QSize Graph::maximumSizeHint() const
{
    return sizeHint();
}

QSize Graph::sizeHint() const
{
    return QSize(500, 200);
}

void Graph::addPoint(int w, int h)
{
    points.append(QPoint(w*2, h*2));
}

void Graph::clearPoints()
{
    points.clear();
}

void Graph::drawGraph() {
    points.prepend(QPoint(0,0)); //The base points of the graph
    points.append(QPoint(500,0));
    update();
    points.clear();
}
```

Comment: Not the answer (Arnold said it anyway), but in your case I would call `Graph::setFixedSize(500, 200)` instead of overriding the various `sizeHint()` methods.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In `drawGraph()`, the call to `update()` posts an event notifying the widget to paint itself. You then clear the points and the `drawGraph()` call exits. After that, the event loop will process the update event and trigger a call to the `paintEvent()` but by then, there are no points in the vector of points to paint.

Don't think of the `paintEvent()` as painting something permanent onto the widget once that will be displayed forever until you clear it and paint something else. The `paintEvent()` needs to be able to paint the widget from scratch whenever it needs to be redrawn. This is often due to a request from the system when the widget is moved, minimized and restored etc. This means your vector of points needs to remain until you no longer want a polygon to be displayed or the points are changed.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you might be adding only two points to your points-list.  I don't think it is possible to have a polygon with only two points; try adding a third point and see if you get a triangle.